# why won't mySQL let me SET return=1?

Tags: mysql

It makes no sense. I have a TINYINT field that is either 0 or 1 and I'm trying to set it like this:

`UPDATE db_products SET return='1' WHERE product_id=342343434`

But it tells me there's a mySQL syntax error. What am I doing wrong here? Is the problem that the field is called return? If so, how do I get around it without changing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, you can get around reserved word problems by enclosing with "ticks"; the quote-like thing that usually shares the ~ key.

```
UPDATE db_products SET `return`='1' WHERE product_id=342343434
```

Comment: Just tried that but neither `"return=1"` nor `"return"=1` seems to work :( Same mySQL error.

Comment: Not double quote, the "backtick" on the upper leftmost corner of US keyboards. (see update for example).

Comment: Stretch that left pinky

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, MySQL specific, but do not behave exactly like " (depends on server config).

Comment: @Uueerdo sorry, I though that was an SQLite question (I saw a lot of those, and I usually don't read MySQL question)

Comment: @njzk2 No prob, after working with MySQL for over a decade now, it is embarassing to admit I didn't know you could even use " for field delimiting until about year ago. ;)